# Encode to JSON from unstructured string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a string that looks like following:

```
{"name": "john", "smith", "paul", "address": "nyc", "chicago", "age": 50, 60}
```

I have to convert this to JSON as following:

```
{"name": ["john", "smith", "paul"], "address": ["nyc", "chicago"], "age": [50, 60]}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What produces the string? Can you have *it* produce valid JSON?

Comment: What difficulties do you have? Do you need guidance how to start? Depending on your needs you could use a regex or a parser-generator such a pyparsing to parse the string into a dictionary or (worse) just insert brackets to make it a valid json

Answer (score 0):

```
str_temp = '{"name": "john", "smith", "paul", "address": "nyc", "chicago", "age": 50, 60}'
index_temp = str_temp.split(',')
temp_flag = 0
temp_list = []
for object in index_temp:
    if object.find(':') != -1:
        if temp_flag == 0:
            temp_count = object.find(':')
            object = object[:temp_count + 1] + '[' + object[temp_count + 1:]+','
            temp_flag = 1;
        else:
            temp_count = object.find(':')
            object = '],' + object[:temp_count + 1] + '[' + object[temp_count + 1:] + ','
    else:
        object = object + ',' 
    temp_list.append(object)
final_str = ''.join(temp_list)
final_str = final_str[:-2] + ']}'
print final_str
```